# Another WPF Set focus problem with Button Click (control not a child at design time)

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls, focus, tabitem

I have a button on a WPF window that adds a tabitem to a tabcontrol on the window.  A user control that fills that tabitem is also created in that event.  I want to set the focus to a textbox on that user control.  I've tried all kinds of txt.Focus code and so forth but the button always still have focus after the click event is executed.

I can't use this as the textbox is not part of the xaml on this window at design time.

MyAttachedProps:EventFocusAttachment.ElementToFocus="{Binding ElementName=NotAvailableAtDesignTime}"

The only thing I can think of is a timer to execute after the button click but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bool attached dependency property.

Bind this to a public bool property in your viewmodel.

Set that to true when you want to focus the control.

I have a bit of code. Can't recall if I wrote it or grabbed it off the web. And I can't recall actually using it either.

```
    public static class FocusExtension
    {
        public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusExtension),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

        private static async void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uie = (UIElement)d;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                await Task.Delay(200);
                uie.Focus();
                Keyboard.Focus(uie);
            }
        }
    }
```

This the await task delay introduces a 200ms wait so other stuff can finish whatever it's doing.  You could instead defer the focussing using dispatcher.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => 
{  
      uie.Focus();
      Keyboard.Focus(uie);
}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Due to closures, that code will capture whatever uie is so long as it's in scope.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a timer to execute just after the button click event.  I went with that for now and it works fine.